# cakephp 4 - How to find max and min values from a related table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm doing some development in CakePHP 4. Still very new to it so this might be straightforward.

I have a table of housing developments that has a simple structure -

```
development_id, name, address, etc
```

Each development has a number of plots for sale that are in a separate table with a structure like -

```
plot_id, development_id, price
```

They are related in the DevelopmentsTable.php file -

```
    $this->hasMany('Plots', [
        'foreignKey' => 'development_id',
    ]);
```

For each development I need to show what the maximum and minimum prices for the plots the development contains are. I’m not at all sure how to go about doing this except by cycling through all the plots in the view and finding the maximum and minimum which doesn’t seem good.

Any suggestions on a better way would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read:

**https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#getting-results**
**https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#window-functions**

Or in your template view or Entity virtual field you can use collections max and min function

**[https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake\Collection\Collection::max](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::max)**

Comment: The Collection solution is exactly what I was after. Thanks.